# Why are there capitalized duplicates appearing in Google Analytics Real-Time reporting?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, reporting, analytics-api, real-time

The following is visible under Real-Time reports in Google Analytics for a single page:

[image]

What is the difference between the lower-case and upper-case search engine names?

> "Google" vs. "google"
>
> "Bing" vs. "bing"

And what is the difference between the "Organic" and "Organic search" mediums?

In other words, why are they showing up differently?

Comment: Do you use some filters in your account?

Comment: +1 and starred: good question. I tried to find the answer but I didn't succeed. Maybe you can ask the question on Google forum.

Comment: @Marian, yes, to filter out employees/IP range

Comment: I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both Google and Bing, you can be logged into an account on their sites when conducting searches. In that case, your search is conducted in a "secured context" for privacy reasons, under which your query terms are not available for reports.

To separate the two, Google Analytics uses a capitalization for the site name versus lower case for the search engine name. It uses the Medium label "Organic search" for secured searches in which the query terms aren't available, and "Organic" for those in which they are (i.e., searches conducted when not logged into an account).

Documentation appears to be almost non-existent on this, though the bottom of the following conveys a little in regards to this: [Google Analytics - Search Overview](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1247841?hl=en)

> When you sign in to Google.com, your organic search is conducted in a
>   secure context. If you visit a site from those search results, the
>   visit is still categorized as organic, but your query terms are not
>   available in the report. The label (not provided) is used in place of
>   the query terms. 
> Referral traffic and cpc traffic are not affected by
>   the secure context, nor are any of your other statistics like
>   conversion rates.

Comment: Interesting! How did you find this out?

Comment: Exhaustive research using Google :-) Then after I found some bits like in the link, I analyzed reports in Google Analytics… Tough question!

Comment: Care to share any of the other research? :)

Comment: As I wrote, this appears to be undocumented (as others also commented). Google searches only led to clues like the above.

Comment: Ah, that's what I meant — the other Google search clues you found? :)

Comment: Just small things I picked up on from various sources like [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1247833?hl=en&ref_topic=1308584), where they indicate they separate the search engine name from the site in sources, use "organic" for the medium but provide the label "organic search" in place of query terms in secured searches (as per the above)... Nothing definitive, but you can confirm my answer by drilling down in the data for the sources in your reports (i.e., looking for query terms). Again, there's no single answer source for this question yet...until you accept the answer :-)

Comment: Great, awarding bounty and accepting for now :)

Comment: This looks very similar to ResponseTap's (you can Google them) source/medium when they are attributing a call for a visitor that made the phone call after visiting the website (ie when they left their computer and noted the phone number) - hope this helps!